# What is Coordinating degree and The Condition certainty degree?

Tags: algorithm, split, cluster-analysis, decision-tree, entropy

I very confussed about this paper

"the basic idea of the splitting property of every branch is determined by the size of coordinating degree and the condition certainty degree"

or this link : https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/10/4/124 page 9 of 18

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l9CI.jpg)